# Wrong/Different Publisher Name

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2014

We have created **InstallScript Basic MSI projects**, all the projects have English, French and Japanese as **Setup Languages**; and English as **default language**.Under General Information tab we filled our **Company name(say XYZ) in Publisher field.**

While running the **setup** if we select English as a language , we can see XYZ as a Publisher name in **Control panel  > programs**. But if we select French or Japanese we have seen **some other names(in french or Japanese) in Publisher column** in control panel > programs

Please help me so that we can get proper publisher name

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you resolved the problem?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot for your help Stein Asmul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***ISString Table***: Not sure what version of Installshield you are using. You can generally add languages in the `General Information` view in the property `Setup Languages`. That should be done already.

- I don't really like the `String Editor` view under `User Interface` in the left application pane.
- I usually try to use the `Direct Editor`. I go to the `ISString table` and sort the string table by the column `ISString` to see all the different languages "next to each other" in the table view.
- Check what the `COMPANY_NAME` string has been set to in the different languages. Three different setup languages in the below table:

[image]

---

***String Editor View***: If you insist on using the `String Editor View`, then you can group the display by dragging the `Identifier` column to the "group by" field on top of the display:

[image: Identifier grouping]

Answer (score 0):

In the "`Add or Remove Programs`" properties of your project you may set the "`Publisher`" property as regular string property (ex.: Write in the field "XYZ Company" directly). In this case no matter what language of installation user choose property will be always the same. On other hand you may set for "`Publisher`" property value from "`String Table`". In this case the `Id` of the chosen string inside each "`String Table`" must be checked/set. Whatever value is set for this string `Id` for particular language, this value will be displayed. Obviously you may set the same value (ex.: "XYZ Company") for all languages supported.